# How to implement edit text with list view in android

Tags: android

I have the listview in my activity. In the list view I have an edit text box with a filled value. I am filling the value using a hashmap. If the user can change the edit text value in list view, I need to update the hashmap and refresh the list view with update values

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain your question into more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Without code, making a bunch of assumptions here...

Inside your custom adapter (in your `getView` method), use `setOnFocusChangeListener` on the EditText and have it fire your code to update the hashmap.

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {                                   // run when focus is lost
            String value = v.getText().toString();         // get the value from the EditText
            // Your code to update hashmap
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: whether above code will refresh the lisview with edit text updated value? or we nedd to call notify dataset change in onfocuschange

Comment: Yes, you would need to call that to refresh the list.